# How can I update Android UI in a coroutine?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have code that crashes when I put code that updates UI in a coroutine. For example:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
//code that makes text box blue
delay(1000L)
}
```

Will crash. I also need to loop the delay several times so I can't use post handlers. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Comment: You need to confine the UI code in the [main dispatcher](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-main.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can update your UI in this way, if you are working on the activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      launch(context = UI) {

        val result = async { loadString() }.await()
        Log.d("TAG", 
            "Post execution thread:"+Thread.currentThread().name)
        textView.text = result   
      }
    }

    private suspend fun loadString() : String {
       Log.d("TAG", "Execution thread: "+Thread.currentThread().name)
       delay(1000L)
       return "Some loaded string..."
   }
}
```